# PHP - Laravel - Trying to get property 'array' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
// billing cycles
                if( $row->tarificaciones->array ) {
                    $j = 0;
                    foreach ($row->tarificaciones->array as $row2) {
                        $rates["billingCycles"][$j] = $row->tarificaciones->array->formaPago;
                        $j++;
                    }
                }else{
                    $rates["billingCycles"][0] = $row->tarificaciones->array->formaPago;
                }
```

Con este código recibo la respuesta del WS y pinto una tabla, en todas las opciones de producto funciona correctamente pero en una en concreto me muestra el error "Trying to get property 'array' of non-object"

En la respuesta que me muestra el error tengo el siguiente Array:

```
+"tarificaciones": {#903 ▼
        +"array": {#904 ▼
          +"formaPago": 1
          +"primaNetaAnual": "50.01"
          +"primaNetaFraccionada": "50.01"
          +"primaTotalAnual": "50.09"
          +"recargosImpuestos": "0.08"
        }
      }
```

En la respuesta que si funciona me llega el siguiente array:

```
+"tarificaciones": {#883 ▼
        +"array": {#884 ▼
          +"formaPago": 1
          +"primaNetaAnual": "50.01"
          +"primaNetaFraccionada": "50.01"
          +"primaTotalAnual": "50.09"
          +"recargosImpuestos": "0.08"
        }
      }
```

No entiendo por que en una combinación recibiendo los mismos datos me muestra error y en otra funciona correctamente.

Añado el error:

```
Trying to get property 'array' of non-object
```

/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imediador-web/app/Http/Middleware/PMWShandler.php#894
ErrorException
}

```
                // billing cycles
                if( is_array($row->tarificaciones->array) ) {
                    $j = 0;
                    foreach ($row->tarificaciones->array as $row2) {
                        $rates["billingCycles"][$j] = $row->tarificaciones->array->formaPago;
```

Comment: En el primer código que pongo.

Comment: Te refieres a esto: